# Parse Push on Android not sending

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push

I'm developing an app for Android,which have a push notification system that uses Parse (https://www.parse.com).

I've already setup the Parse on my app exactly as they instructs on their tutorials, and it is working - if I send the notifications "manually" from the Parse panel, it is received with no problems.

But when I try to send the push notifications from inside the app, the pushes never gets to it's destination channel, and it does not show up in the Parse logs either.

Take a look on my code:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

public Application() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "MY_CODE", "MY_OTHER_CODE");
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("");       

    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setChannel( "my_example_channel" );
    push.setMessage( "Test message" );
    push.sendInBackground( new SendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) Log.d("push", "success!");
            else Log.d("push", "failure");
        }
    });


}
```

The callback returns null - no errors are shown and it logs "success", and the other mobile that I'm using to test the app is subscribed to the "my_example_channel" - it receives notifications if I send them through the Parse Dashboard.

I've also tried to put the "Push send code" (the previous code, without the "Parse.initialize..." and "parsePush.subscribeInBackground..." parts) on a Button click, and on an "onCreate" method of an Activity, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved it! It seems that you have to enable Client Side Push in your Parse Settings. Settings > Push > Client push enabled? >Yes. I was struggling with it all last night!!

Comment: It's also good to note that they don't promote client-side push because of vulnerability issues. Here's a great read:  http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/